# How to parse the text from an anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, html, beautifulsoup, pyqt4, python-3.6

I want to parse this "`<a href="javascript:8==99999?popDuelloDialog(2754288):popTeam(2386)">Gnistan</a>`" and extract the text.

I tried to extract a lot, but I couldn't succeed.

I don't know how to build a method with this format "javascript comes "`:(numbers)`" which are not repeating. So I need such a method that will only use the repeating part and will extract text in the body.

My code is here:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebPage
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

class Client(QWebPage):

    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.on_page_load)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def on_page_load(self):
        self.app.quit()

url = 'http://www.mackolik.com/Genis-Iddaa-Programi'
client_response = Client(url)
source = client_response.mainFrame().toHtml()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
#pattern=re.compile(r"javascript:;")
#js_test = soup.find_all('a', href='javascript')
hreff=soup.find_all("a","javascript:;")
#js_test=soup.select('a[href^="javascript:\('(.*?)'\);"]')
#print(js_test.text)
#type(href)
for i in hreff:
    print(hreff[i])
```

Comment: You just want to parse "Gnistan" ?

Comment: Yeah. First of all i want to parse "Gnistan", on the same page there are many texts that i want to parse, then of course i will apply the same method for others.

Comment: @TylerH, you changed and generalized the topic name which does not make easier to reach and find that kind of question. I believe there are plenty of people who search on the same thing but never understands from the generalized terms such as anchor tag. It is easier to search on google "<a href="javascript:" that kind of search, which is easier to realize that this related to their search. I think you should re-evaluate your edit. Thanks...

Comment: @A.Kaymakci No one else in the world will likely need to parse the exact string you did. If someone wants to know how to parse a string, they don't search for "how to parse <xyzstring>", they search for "how to parse a string". Questions are more useful when they are oriented toward more people.

Comment: @TylerH you are looking at the problem from the view of software engineer and i respect it of course, but i want to show you also there are some poeple like me, who do not know about all kind of technical terms because while tags, anchor tags terms etc belong to HTML and XML programming, print, for terms are more general and belong to e.g. Python. I donot have to know about HTML and so on, if i am interested only in Python language. You could look and think this way either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC all you need is to make BeautifulSoup get all anchors tag that have the `"javascript"` in their `href` attribute. However, it seems that the content you want to parse are being created with JavaScript, and that would require using `selenium` and a webdriver like `ChromeDriver`. Using BeautifulSoup and requests we can see that the content you probably want is not in the html code, the logic for solving your issue would be this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = "http://www.mackolik.com/Genis-Iddaa-Programi"
data = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.findAll('a'):
    if "javascript" in tag['href']:
        print(tag.text)
```

The code above checks if the substring `"javascript"` is **`in`** the `href` attribute and prints the tag's text if true.

With selenium and ChromeDriver the logic is pretty much the same, but we need other methods:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.mackolik.com/Genis-Iddaa-Programi"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

for tag in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a"):
    if "javascript" in tag.get_attribute("href"):
        print(tag.text)
```

Comment: Thank you @Vinicius Aguiar. It works fine. Now i will edit the code then it will print out in nice form. Thanks a lot again. Your solution is smart.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this I know it's in VB but you can take the idea...

```
'look for the begining of <a href
    Dim xstr As String = "<a href=javascript:8==99999?popDuelloDialog(2754288):popTeam(2386)>Gnistan</a>"
    Dim xStart As Integer = InStr(xstr, "<a href")
    If xStart > 0 Then
        'look for the end
        Dim AHREF As Integer = InStr(xStart, xstr, ">") + 1
        'look for </a>
        Dim endAHREF As Integer = InStr(AHREF, xstr, "</a>")
        'take what you need
        Dim Result As String = Mid(xstr, AHREF, endAHREF - AHREF)


    End If
```

Comment: You apply here divide and conquer operation. You divided the anchor tag into two piece then subtract from each other then find the parsed text. I will try this method by myself. If I can succeed it i will share it in here.

Comment: yeah exactly. then if you want to do a bunch of them then just remove everything before "</a>" in your string and repeat the loop.